How to standardise confidence intervals for a regression with parallel mediation
I've run a regression with parallel mediation on SPSS using Hayes Process Macro, and it calculated the standardised beta for me - but I've just realised that the 95% confidence intervals are all unstandardised! Is there a way for me to manually calculate the ULCI and LLCI myself?
I found a calculation on a similar post for working it out by hand (I'm desperate), but when I did it I was coming up with CIs that were things like -41.54.
Thank you in advance!

Without some reproducible minimal example, some data, and so more information on how you made the calculations, it's going to be hard to answer your question. Consider improving it a bit.
